# Server doesn't listen - Postgres 9.5.4 - Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, postgresql

Postgres is not connecting on localhost. At other connections, it works just fine.
I haven't change any configuration settings, it was working just fine. Somehow, it stopped working.

This is the error (i got this today, before that whenever I tried to connect, application crashed on Win8)

> The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
>   could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Try connecting to it's ip instead of `localhost` and see what happens

Comment: How are you trying to connect to it?

Comment: I'm trying to connect via pgAdmin III, and there's an Java application I'm developing that connects to local database.

Comment: I re-install, reboot my computer several times over the days I got the error and postgres still not work ONLY on localhost connections.

Comment: is your firewall allowing the connection to the port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled once again postgres, and it's working fine now.

Edit: I uninstalled postgres, deleted folder on C:/Program Files, installed it again and it works now.
I havent change any conf files in both times. Still no clue why it stopped connecting only localhost servers.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer. If you could expand upon what you did differently during the second installation it may help others in the future.